# How to add value to apache server header

Tags: apache-2.2

The currrent value of apache server header is

```
Server: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) PHP/5.4.5
```

I want to modify/add a value to it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Server` header is controlled by the [`ServerTokens`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servertokens) directive; `mod_headers` cannot touch the `Server` header being sent with a response.

If one of the options there doesn't suit your needs, you can recompile to change the hard-coded value, `mod_security` can alter it, or a proxy in front of Apache (including another Apache running `mod_proxy` and `mod_headers`) can alter the response headers after they've been sent.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify source according to this:

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Apache/Server-Limits-for-Apache-Security/3/

File: ap_release.h

```
  #define SERVER_BASEVENDOR   "Apache Group"
  #define SERVER_BASEPRODUCT  "Apache" 
  #define SERVER_BASEREVISION "1.3.29" 
  #define SERVER_BASEVERSION SERVER_BASEPRODUCT "/" SERVER_BASEREVISION 
  #define SERVER_PRODUCT  SERVER_BASEPRODUCT
  #define SERVER_REVISION SERVER_BASEREVISION
  #define SERVER_VERSION  SERVER_PRODUCT "/" SERVER_REVISION
```

And build your own binary.

You can also try to turn off sensitive information like the Apache version using the ServerTokens and ServerSignature settings in your httpd.conf (If it's a point of this modification)